# Running total sql SAP B1 - Not found a proper way to resolve it

Tags: sql, aggregate, cumulative-sum, sapb1

I tried to have a running total row at the bottom of my table by running this following SQL code.

```
SELECT
T1.[ItemCode],T4.[ItmsGrpNam],
CASE
WHEN T3.[OnHand] - SUM(T1.[OpenQty]) < SUM(T1.[OpenQty])
THEN T3.[OnHand] - SUM(T1.[OpenQty])
ELSE
SUM(T1.[OpenQty])
END As 'Missing Quantity'

FROM ORDR T0
INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
INNER JOIN OITW T3 ON T2.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode
INNER JOIN OITB T4 ON  T2.ItmsGrpCod=T4.ItmsGrpCod

WHERE 
 T3.[WhsCode] = T1.[WhsCode]
and  T0.[DocDueDate] <=  '[%D1]'
and (T4.[ItmsGrpNam] = 'Commercial' Or T4.[ItmsGrpNam] = 'Residentiel')


GROUP BY T1.[ItemCode],T3.[OnHand],T4.[ItmsGrpNam]

HAVING T3.[OnHand] - SUM(T1.[OpenQty]) < 0 Or SUM(T1.[OpenQty]) < 0

UNION ALL

SELECT 'See', 'Total Missing Quantity' ,  CASE
WHEN T3.[OnHand] - SUM(T1.[OpenQty]) < SUM(T1.[OpenQty])
THEN T3.[OnHand] - SUM(T1.[OpenQty])
ELSE
SUM(T1.[OpenQty])
END

FROM ORDR T0
INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
INNER JOIN OITW T3 ON T2.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode
INNER JOIN OITB T4 ON  T2.ItmsGrpCod=T4.ItmsGrpCod

WHERE 
 T3.[WhsCode] = T1.[WhsCode]
and  T0.[DocDueDate] <=  '[%D1]'
and (T4.[ItmsGrpNam] = 'Commercial' Or T4.[ItmsGrpNam] = 'Residentiel')
```

I have this error message '
1). [Microsoft] [SQL Server Native Client 11.0] [SQL Server] The 'OITW.OnHand' column is not valid in the selection list because it is not contained in an aggregate function or in the clause BY GROUP. 2). [Microsoft] [SQL Server Native Client 11.0] [SQL Server] Can not prepare statements. 'User Defined Values' (CSHS)'

When I try to

```
GROUP BY T1.[ItemCode],T3.[OnHand],T4.[ItmsGrpNam]

HAVING T3.[OnHand] - SUM(T1.[OpenQty]) < 0 Or SUM(T1.[OpenQty]) < 0
```

In the second part of the query, I get multiple rows when I only want one that sum all.

I spent the day to figure this out and there's multiple answers on the NET but I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Does anyone can help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: GROUP BY clause should have all the columns which you have in the select clause for an aggregate function

Comment: It's true but when I tried it, it gaves me multiple lines with different values. I want a SUM TOTAL row of all found quantities 'Total Missing Quantity'. Thanks